# googlemaps api3, demogallery example "Custom Small Navigation Control"

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

This may not be the best place for this question but here goes:

I'm a beginner in googlemaps and javascript and found this example for something I'm working on.
http://search.missouristate.edu/map/mobile/examples/ZoomPanControl.htm
I understand most of the code but I'm having a hard time finding out the meaning of the following lines of code at the end of this file ZoomPanControl.js

```
window["missouristate"] = window["missouristate"] || {};
window["missouristate"]["web"] = window["missouristate"]["web"] || {};
window["missouristate"]["web"]["ZoomPanControl"] = ZoomPanControl;
```

**Edit:** The [original example](http://search.missouristate.edu/map/mobile/examples/ZoomPanControl.htm) is no longer available and redirects to a map that doesn't have the custom ZoomPanControl, [here is an example that shows the custom zoom/pan control referenced](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_GoogleEx_control-custom_ZoomPanControl.html)

Answer (score 0):

It's appending the control to the global variable(or namespace?) 'window', so that you can instantiate it using:

```
 var ZoomPanControl = new missouristate.web.ZoomPanControl(map);
```

The [**Google Maps API loader**](http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false) does the same thing, namely:

```
window.google = window.google || {};
google.maps = google.maps || {};
```

Comment: Thanks, that helps some, I guess I need to read more about the DOM and how namespaces work.