# how to show large zoom scroll in google map api

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have to show large zoom slider option which was available in previous version of google map api (v3.21). I have already specified the version in the src of script but it won't work. Below is my code:

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="googleMap" style="height: 100%;width: 1349px;"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
  var map;
  function initialize() {
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('googleMap'), {
      center: {lat: -34.397, lng: 150.644},
      zoom: 2,
      streetViewControl: false,
      panControl: true,
      panControlOptions: {
        position: google.maps.ControlPosition.RIGHT_TOP
      },
      zoomControl: true,
      zoomControlOptions: {
        style: google.maps.ZoomControlStyle.LARGE,
        position: google.maps.ControlPosition.RIGHT_TOP
      },
    });
  }
</script>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?callback=initialize&v=3.21&signed_in=true"></script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "old" pan and zoom control has been removed.  If you still want that functionality, you need to create your own custom control to implement it.

Related questions (include examples of a custom pan/zoom control):

- [Google maps custom control always appears below the default controls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21266309/google-maps-custom-control-always-appears-below-the-default-controls) (contains a custom pan control)
- [googlemaps api3, demogallery example “Custom Small Navigation Control”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12149305/googlemaps-api3-demogallery-example-custom-small-navigation-control) (contains a custom pan/zoom control)

Answer (score 0):

> The Zoom control is now just a "+" and "-" button - there is no longer
>   a slider. The default position of the Zoom control has changed from
>   TOP_LEFT to RIGHT_BOTTOM

to know more check

> Zoom control

block in this link [What's New in the v3.22 Map Controls](https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/v322-controls-diff)

Comment: i knw its depricated but i have specified the version which allow me to use that version property.

Comment: Version 3.21 was retired, it is no longer available.

Comment: do one thing remove signed_in=true and see what happens.

Answer (score 0):

I've developed a zoom slider for IE11. It could also work for Chrome and Mozilla, updating the css properties.

https://github.com/bubango/zoom_slider_IE11

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you're still looking for a zoom slider, but I made one recently and maybe you or anyone else can use it.

Create a zoom constructor...

```
function ZoomControl(controlDiv, map, min, max, currentZoom) {

  var controlUI = document.createElement('input');
  controlUI.type = 'range';
  controlUI.value = currentZoom;
  controlUI.min = min;
  controlUI.max = max;
  controlUI.style.position = "fixed";
  controlUI.style.top = "95%";
  controlUI.style.left = "50%";
  controlUI.style.transform = "translate(-50%, -50%)";
  controlUI.style.width = "400px";
  controlDiv.appendChild(controlUI);
  controlUI.addEventListener('click', function() {
    map.setZoom(parseFloat(controlUI.value));
  });

  google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'zoom_changed', function(){
      controlUI.value = map.getZoom();
  });

}
```

and use it when you create a map.

```
function initMap() {

    //initial map options
    var options = {
        center: startLatLng,
        zoom: 3,
        minZoom: 3,
        maxZoom: 15,
        streetViewControl: false,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN,
        disableDefaultUI: true
        }

    map = new google.maps.Map(id('map'), options);

    var centerControlDiv = document.createElement('div');
    var centerControl = new ZoomControl(centerControlDiv, map, options.minZoom, options.maxZoom, options.zoom);

    centerControlDiv.index = 1;
    map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.BOTTOM_CENTER].push(centerControlDiv);

}
```

Your result will have a slider that looks like the attached image.[image: zoom example]

Comment: What CSS must I use to create this style thumb slider please? The above code just produces a black square!

Comment: @Archdeacon there is no fancy css. I am using a poor performance friendly javascript by appending styles in the function ZoomControl. You can create a class with these styles, and append all the styles at once via JS.

You can see a working version of this slider, without a google map here: https://codepen.io/Fallenstedt/pen/vgJbYd

Comment: I eventually used the code here - http://brennaobrien.com/blog/2014/05/style-input-type-range-in-every-browser.html